# Is it possible to iterate on every single page of a Google Document in Apps Script? How can I do that?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I got a Google Docs made of several pages (not a fixed number..) and each of them is filled with an unspecified number of text paragraphs. I need to put a unique title on top of every page and I thought to do that using an array where all titles are listed..

titles = [title1, title2, title3 ...];

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that even reading documentation..
Is there a way to loop through document pages in apps script?
The script should also understand if a paragraph starts in a page and ends in another, just to avoid cutting it off in two parts.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions here..Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

You would need to have a Page Break at the end of each page because there is no other way to know how many paragraphs are on a page.  Also when adding your unique headers you have to be careful to not disturb the pagination.

But here is an example of how to find the page breaks for each page.  I leave it to you to figure out how to insert the "title" paragraph.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paras = body.getParagraphs();
    for( let i=0; i<paras.length; i++ ) {
      let para = paras[i];
      let nChild = para.getNumChildren();
      if( nChild > 0 ) {
        let child = para.getChild(nChild-1);
        if( child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK ) {
          console.log("page break");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```